# A horizontal plank is moving towards right over a system of 3 roller drums as shown .the ratio of transilational spped of smaller and larger drum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

[image] the ans for 21st is 1A horizontal plank is moving towards right over a system of 3 roller drums as shown .the ratio of transilational spped of smaller and larger drum

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an interesting question with a non-intuitive answer.

If the top of a roller (or a wheel) is moving at speed $s$ and the bottom of the roller does not slip, so it is stationary at the instant it touches the ground, what is the speed of the centre of the roller (or the axle of the wheel) ? Does this speed depend on the radius of the roller or wheel ?

Comment: The roller will have diff angular acceleration but the linear  acceleration for non slipping will be same for all 3